# How do I search in zips or jars?

Tags: command-line

I want to search for some file(class) in zips(jars). How to do it from command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "**unzip -l zip-file-name.zip**" to list the contents of the zip file, pipe its output to grep and then use grep to check if the list contains the file you are looking for.

```
unzip -l file.zip|grep file.class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jar -tf foobar.jar foo/bar/Foobar.class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the proper answer would be: use [`zgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/zgrep.1.html) instead of `grep`.